# Is there a way to increase movement speed?

Tags: stardew-valley

Running is so insanely slow to me. While I'm working on my farm or mining it's alright, but traveling to different parts of the map can take minutes at a time.

Is there a way to speed up the running process, like buying a pair of running shoes or something?

Comment: Not really answering the question, but completing all the packages in the Boiler room of the community centre will repair the minecarts stationed in the mines/bus stop/ next to the blacksmith respectively, which will allow you to instantly transport from one place to another for free. It helps out a lot

Comment: @CoqPwner That would seem to solve the real problem rather than the literal question, which would make a good answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to increase your running speed, you can buy Coffee in the Saloon for $300, which will increase your running speed for two minutes. Make sure to stock a lot of those if you are going for this option.

You also have the possibility to use some cooking recipes to craft the following items :

- A Pepper Poppers for 1 Hot Pepper and 1 Cheese
- A Spicy Eel for 1 Eel and 1 Hot Pepper
- A Super Meal for 1 Bok Choy, 1 Cranberry and 1 Hazelnut.

All of those will also add one point to your speed for a certain
   amount of time.

Later in the game, you can also obtain a horse as soon as you will have built a Stable. The stable comes with the horse when you buy it which is an added bonus.

Comment: Pepper Poppers will also increase your movement speed (I think by 1 for about 5 minutes).

Comment: That's indeed true. Thanks, I'm adding this to the answer.

Comment: The horse, definitely the horse.  It significantly increases your speed, and the horse is smart: It'll wait around for you even if you take a mine cart elsewhere and later return, and no matter where you leave it, it's back at its stable the next morning.  Had I known how good the horse was, I would have prioritized it way more than getting cows and chickens.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, but it seems that when I have a speed buff (like from Pepper Poppers), it stacks with the movement speed of the horse too, so that even the horse moves faster. Or maybe it's just my imagination. Can anyone else confirm whether or not speed buffs work while you're riding the horse as well?

Comment: @Kyralessa I'm going to love my horse when I get it. I'm going to get a stable asap!

Comment: I just want to add that you can buy individual coffee seeds from the traveling merchant occasionally. When planted, these seeds grow into coffee plants that give more seeds. The number of coffee plants you farm can grow exponentially, and eventually you can make your own coffee for really cheap - it costs only 5 beans to make one coffee in a keg, and with enough plants you'll be swimming in coffee beans.

Comment: @DarthPizza Speed buffs do stack with the horse. You can see this more clearly if you get hit by the slime debuff (in the secret woods for example) and then immediately jump on your horse, who will also move much slower (though  still faster than slime-walking).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, you can actually grow your own coffee beans now, and brew your own coffee. So no more reliance on the saloon for coffee! (Check the travelling cart, she will occasionally sell coffee beans you can plant)

Answer (score 6):

There's four ways:

- Pepper Poppers (+1 Speed for ~6 min 30 sec)
- Spicy Eel (+1 Speed for idk how long)
- Coffee (+1 Speed for ~1 minute)
- Horse (Costs 10000G, 100 hardwood (get it from the secret forest), and 5  iron bars, increases movement speed by 30%)

Remember that +1 Speed and Horses stack, so you can literally go SANIC FAST!

Also, as mentioned, the minecarts are an awesome way to move around. You can instantly travel to the mines, the bus stop, the other side of town by the blacksmith, and the quarry (if you've unlocked it).

Answer (score 0):

Pathways not on the farm make you move faster by +0.1.

Answer (score -1):

**HERE'S THE ONLY COMBO YOU NEED**

**1. Crab Cakes** *(16min 40sec)*

**2. Coffee** *(1min 20sec)*

**3. Horse**